# Regex to allow separator only when both parts are present

Tags: regex, datetime, regex-lookarounds

Currently I'm writing a regex to validate datetime strings. The basic format is

```
(Date)(?: *,?)(Time)
```

I've worked out the date and time portions of the regex just fine, but I'm having trouble making the regex allow for all three of these cases:

- date and no separator and no time
- date and separator and time
- no date and no separator and time

The easy way (making all three parts optional) has the unintended side-effect of allowing the case

- no date and separator and no time

Is this something that can be achieved with a lookaround?

Example valid input:

- `January 25 2004, 10:30 PM`
- `2004-1-25`
- `10:30 PM`

Invalid input:

- `,`

(The Date and Time regexes handle a bunch of cases, and I've got that worked out - it's preventing that invalid case while allowing for all three forms that I still need.)

Comment: @Avinash - I added some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include the separator with either the date or time group, then a separator by itself will not match:

```
^(DATE(?: *,? *))?(TIME)?$
```

It has an optional date and separator, followed by an optional time.

See demo: http://regex101.com/r/dH6nI2/1

Comment: I would use a capturing group for the separator so group 1 and 3 include the date and time, right now the separator would be included in the first match group.

Comment: You're completely right - I was overcomplicating things. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use alternation:

```
((Date)((?: *,?)(Time))?|((Date)(?: *,?))?(Time))
```

Though it would lead to some duplication.

Comment: That requires repeating the Date and Time parts of the regex though, right? I'm trying to avoid that as it's already pretty long. I think I found a solution though, posting in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution which works. I use a lookahead at the beginning to verify that it doesn't start with a separator... and then make the separator an optional part of the time section.

```
/^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])(Date)(?:(?:Separator)?(Time))$/
```

As an example, to validate datetimes with the date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` and times in the format `HH:ii` and Separator `, *| +` (optional comma and one or more spaces), it would be

```
/^(?=[0-9])(?:([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}))?(?:(?:, *| +)?([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}))?$/
```

Comment: You could use Negative Lookahead, `^(?!Sep$)(Date)?(?:Sep)?(Time)?$`

Comment: @Avinash - It fails because the example I've given in the answer doesn't include support for string versions of months. I didn't include that in order to simplify the example regex.

Comment: @hwnd Thanks! I guess that a lookahead for non-separator characters and your negative lookahead for separator characters are two sides of the same coin.